# How to display contingency table on a new window in R

Tags: r, regression, decision-tree, contingency

I want to display the contingency table relative to decision tree regression in a new window.

when I execute this line :

```
table(filteredDataFinal$rate, predArbreDecision)
```

The contingency table is displaying on the R console.
like the following image :

[image]

And what I want is something like the following image

[image]

As you see the second figure does not seem to be as the first

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example and your desired output. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I have edited my post. You can now view the desired output.

Comment: What you are showing is the data viewer/editor inside RGui. It is not really capable of displaying contingency tables like you wish to. You can get there, sort of, with `View(as.data.frame.matrix(table(letters[1:3],letters[1:3])))` (using some made-up data).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks   @thelatemail

```
  View(as.data.frame.matrix(table(letters[1:3],letters[1:3])))
```

It works.